# constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake Not working

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

What i can change this code working on iOS 8.I am newer in iOS. Please help any help would be apperciated.

```
return [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:messageTextSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake([PTSMessagingCell maxTextWidth], CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Answer (score 0):

Now As constrainedToSizeusage:lineBreakMode: usage is deprecated in iOS 7.0:

in Greater version of IOS 7. You can use this types of code.

```
// Let's make an NSAttributedString first
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringHere];
//Add LineBreakMode
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
[paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[attributedString  setAttributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle} range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
// Add Font
[attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];

//Now let's make the Bounding Rect
CGSize expectedSize = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:maximumSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil].size;
```

Comment: @ruchi gupta ..i think it's helpful for you.